# Does kicker make my spell multicolor?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

An opponent was playing with a [Rewards of Diversity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRewards%20of%20Diversity%5d), which makes him gain 4 life each time one of his opponents plays a multicolored spell.

I played [Probe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProbe%5d) ({2}{U}) and paid the kicker cost (an extra {1}{B}).

Does Probe count as a multicolored spell? Does my opponent gain 4 life?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Probe is not a multicolored spell, regardless of whether it was kicked.

The color of a card is based solely on the mana cost defined in the top-right corner.  Using a Kicker ability (or anything else that modifies the cost of the card) does not change the color of the card.

---

Relevant entries from the comprehensive rules (emphasis mine):

> **105.2.** An object can be one or more of the five colors, or it can be no color at all. **An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost**, regardless of the color of its frame. An object’s color or colors may also be defined by a color indicator or a characteristic-defining ability. See rule 202.2.
>
> **202.1.** A card’s mana cost is indicated by **mana symbols near the top of the card.** (See rule 107.4.) On most cards, these symbols are printed in the upper right corner. *Some cards from the Future Sight set have alternate frames in which the mana symbols appear to the left of the illustration.*
>
> **202.4.** Any additional cost listed in an object’s rules text or imposed by an effect **isn’t part of the mana cost**.

Comment: It does, however, have a blue/black *color identity*.  Color Identity is used solely for determining card legality in Commander/Brawl decks, and is determined by the colors of all mana symbols in a card's cost and rules text.  (See Rule 903.4)

Comment: Also, cards without mana costs (other than lands, which are colorless) use a *color indicator* (Rule 204) to define their color, and there are various characteristic-defining abilities like Devoid, [Painter's Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146022) , and [Moonlace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=116391) which affect colors as well.